# I moved my drupal 7 website from a remote server to a local computer (Aquia Dev Desktop) and can't login

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I've come to you many times before in search of answers and have always found them without having to post a question; for that, I'd like to start by thanking the community.  This time however, all the answers that I've found haven't seemed to work for me.  Here's what's going on.

I have a site at www.gsntechnologies.com currently built and running with no issues.  We have recently made it a commerce site, so I used Acquia Dev Desktop to set up a local instance of the site for testing purposes and have run into some issues.  For some reason, I am unable to login to the site.  When logging in I receive the error...

"500 Internal Server Error ... The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

This is what I have tried so far...

1) I've tried altering the settings.php file.  I found other posts regarding the $cookie_domain variable being commented out.  I have verified that the line is not commented and changed it from the actual URL (gsntechnologies.com/main) to the following:

gsntech.localhost:8082 | .gsntech.localhost:8082 | localhost:8082 | gsntech.localhost

After that failed, I attempted to comment the line out and try again, still no luck...

With every change I stop the stack then restart, "goto my site", and attempt to login again only to receive the same error.

2) Also in the settings.php file I viewed the database section of the file and attempted to change the 'host' and 'port' variable from the value it is set to while online to the local host info.  (e.g. 'host' => gsntech.localhost   'port' => '8082') but this stopped the site from working altogether so I reverted back to the original setting and the site began to work again.

3) I have verified that mod_rewrite is active in the .htaccess file by searching for "RewriteEngine on".  It was already set to on so no change was made.

4) I have verified that my php.ini file varaible post_max_size was set to 8 as opposed to 0.  Again, this was set correctly when the file was opened so no change was made.

5) I have attempted to create a new account but I am unable to get to the page.  Instead I receive the same error stated above.

At this point I'm stumped.  I'm not sure what other information would be required to figure this out, but if I have left something out please let me know and I'll supply it.  I think it's also important to note that after trying something new and receiving the error again, just to try it, I refresh from the server directly as opposed to from cache.  (Shift+F5 instead of F5).

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Signed,

Why Do Computers Hate Me?

Comment: Try in database settings host = 127.0.0.1 and port = 3306. 8082 is seems is being used for the http traffic not the mysql traffic.

Comment: Actually according to this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22917/looking-for-acquia-dev-desktop-database-settings it looks like it may be using port 33066.

Comment: Have you looked in the error.log what the reason of the 500 error is?

Comment: I'm assuming when you moved the site you moved the files as well as mirroring the production database to your local db, correct?

Comment: Nate, thanks for pitchinin... I've tried modifying the host and password as you've suggested.  While the site works with the changes and I can click 'Manage my database' and view the tables, I'm still unable to login.  I've also tried through Chrome's incognito mode as to get rid of the cache aspect of the problem... still no avail

Comment: Have you looked in the error.log what the reason of the 500 error is?

Comment: Yes, I used FileZilla to copy the files from the remote server to the local path and did an sql dump (I think that's the correct phrase) for the databases and imported the .sql file.

Comment: No, I mean the 500 error you get when logging in must have left an entry in Apache's `error.log` file. It will be a more verbose message telling you what went wrong.

Comment: Pekka, I have.  Unfortunately I'm primarily a desktop application developer.  This is the first website I've ever built, it's been a learning experience the whole way.  The error log states the following:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configureation error."  It then goes on to site a few variables that could be implemented to fix the problem (LimitInternalRecursion)  It then says "Use 'LogeLevel debug' to get a backtrace, but I'm not sure where I would add this code.

Comment: I've just checked the following files for LimitInternalRecursion:

.htaccess | settings.php | authorize.php | php.ini

...no luck

Comment: So you are getting a redirect loop. Normally this is an issue with the cookie, because it logs in thinks it creates a cookie then forwards you on to a page that needs the cookie, but it doesn't exist so it sends you back to the login in a loop.

Comment: What is the url you are going to in your browser? Make sure you cookie domain matches it. If it is `gsntech.localhost:8082` set your cookie domain to `.gsntech.localhost` don't set a port number in your cookie domain.

Comment: Doing some searching on the LimitInternalRecursion variable brought me to a site suggesting to comment out the 'RewriteBase' line (The actual site is in a subfolder)

Doing so got rid of the error page, but now it just directs me back to the login page

Comment: Do you have access to the database via PHPmyadmin or some other tool. Look in table `sessions` see if a session exists with your user id. If there are multiple I would try emptying this table.

Comment: HAHAHA!  Thanks guys, I can't express how much I appreciate the help.  After following Pekka's advice to look deeper into the error log file and tracking the internal recursion to comment out the rewrite base var, then following Pitchinnate's advice to remove the port from the cookie domain and follow whatever site was named in the address bar (it didn't have a preceding dot (gsntech.localhost))  everything is working as expected.  Once again, StackOverflow has saved the day.  Thanks again.